# Is this macro ok to describe an array based UUID / GUID literal?

Tags: c, uuid, guid

I need to implement a UUID or GUID type in "plain C", similar to standard or primitive types, that allows literals.

I using;

```
typedef
  uint32_t uuid[4];
```

And, I'm trying to use a compound array literal in a macro:

```
#define UUID_C(A,B,C,D) ((uint32_t[4]) {A,B,C,D})
```

So I can declare sonething like;

```
void DoSomething(uuid ID) { ... }

int main(...)
{
  DoSomething(UUID_C(0xFF, 0xA5, 0x47, 0x7D));
}
```

I have try other implementations of a UUID type like a `struct` or an object, or other arrays.

Any ideas ?

Comment: It would make more sense to make it a struct. Typedefing an array of a fixed size is unusual. You also cannot return `uuid` from a function if it's defined this way. If it's an array, compiler won't warn you if you pass it to a function accepting `uint32_t`, even if it has nothing to do with uuids. [Something like this would make more sense](https://godbolt.org/z/Z3__o6).

Comment: There's an awful lot of zero bytes in that example — improbably many (12 of 16 bytes are zero).

Comment: Also, prefer functions over macros (a static inline function inside the header behaves like a strongly typed macro, and allows the compiler to help you): [this example](https://godbolt.org/z/W-fpRS). You will likely want to avoid returning these structs by value, but the key point is that the struct behaves like a plain value type, while the array is passed around like a pointer.

Comment: @Groo I'll checked out. Thanks.